# Rails acts_as_taggable_on implemantation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to implemant [acts_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) in my website.

I have ran the installation setup and it worked fine. I am struggling at how to wrote the code to make it work.

The error I am getting right is the following : `undefined method 'each' for "tag1, tag2, tag3":String` at line 29 which is `@video = Video.new(params[:video])`.

Here is what I have...

Video controller

```
acts_as_taggable
```

In my form

```
= f.text_field :tags
```

In my model

```
@video = Video.new(params[:video])
@video.tag_list = params[:video][:tags]
if @video.save
  ...
```

Comment: It'd be great if you could provide some details as to the exact line in the code the error you mention is referring to, as well as that code in context if it is code you wrote yourself *(vs. code from the `acts_as_taggable_on` gem)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting this error because you are passing `params[:video]` which, among other attributes, contains data for the `:tags` attribute in your `Video` model. This is a problem because it's going to use the `acts_as_taggable_on`'s writer method for `tags=`, which expects an `Array`, not a `String`, unlike `tag_list=` which *does* expect a `String`.

One solution, keeping most of your code as is would be to remove `:tags` from the `params` and pass it to `tag_list=`:

```
tags_str = params[:video].delete(:tags)
@video   = Video.new(params[:video])
@video.tag_list = tags_str

if @video.save
  # ...
```

There are of course many variations on the above to get a working solution. For one, you could just give `tags=` what is wants, splitting `:tags` in `params` to an `Array`

```
video_params = params[:video]
video_params[:tags] = video_params[:tags].split(/\,\s*/)
@video   = Video.new(video_params)

if @video.save
  # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think `split!` does not exist however

Comment: And only the first solution worked. In the second, acts_as_taggable_on was complaining it was not receiving a Tag element.